My desktop wifi is getting disconnected after working for a while, and shows no networks in the WiFi tab until I reboot the system
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


~$lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: fc:34:97:96:b5:e6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-44-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:33 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc804000-fc804fff memory:fc800000-fc803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: d8:c0:a6:59:14:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=6.5.0-44-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.34 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:72 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc700000-fc70ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.


~$uname -r
6.5.0-44-generic


When I run the same above command while it is disconnected it either shows network DISABLED or UNCLAIMED
I have tried downgrading the kernel as well as enabling and reinstalling the network manager but the error persists,
sometimes i remains connected for a while like right now but suddenly it will issue a disconnection warning and there would be no networks visible.
I have to reboot the system everytime it happens,and sometimes even rebooting once doesnt helps, ive to restart the system multiple times to get it show my wifi adapter.
HELP!!!!!!!

Is this a server or desktop? Please edit the question and add this info.

Its my desktop, the problem surfaced after I upgraded my kernel to 6.9.3. I downgraded it to 6.5.0 and for now it seems to be working fine but I just want to make sure the problem is fixed.

Then how is it you are running the 6.9.3 kernel? This is not the kernel or even the kernel series the OS came with.

Sorry if my response was not clear, I referred to some similar solutions here on the site and one suggested to use the latest kernel which I downloaded using mainline. https://imgur.com/3djz9yl
I

By latest I am sure they meant Ubuntu latest. Ubuntu does not use the 6.9 on any version yet.

Alright, even though the problem has become less frequent after the downgrade, it still persists. Can you point me to where I should look for configuration errors or something similar?
